# Is there an efficient way to Generate Folders using compiled-time source generator in c#?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators, system.io.directory

**Compiled-time source generator for folders:**

Is there an efficient way to make the [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) **generate folders at compile time, not just files?**

Note: I know that I can use *System.IO*, but I do not think that this is the best solution, and I prefer to write as follows:

```
context.AddSource(" folder /file.g.cs", "source");
```

- I tried `context.AddSource(" folder /file.g.cs", "source");`

I expected that it would generate a folder named "folder" and inside it a file "file.g.cs" and this file contains the word "source" at compile time.

This will not work but will give an error message with the character number '\'.

- I tried to deal with the files using the *System.IO* library, but because of this, the folder will not be modified at compile time, and it will not be added to the default path.

Comment: Why do you want to use source generators? You use the to dynamically create code, not folders. You probably need to use a relative path. Also check the documentation for strings to find out how to deal with backslashes in path names.  There are severalcorrect ways to deal with them.

Comment: I'm working on my bachelor's degree graduation project, where the idea is A source generator (tool) that analyses an unorganized source code determined by the developer, and generate edited copy of the content into different folders and files  depending on multiple constraints determined by the developer. This work is done in compile time.
This will help the developers to architect their unorganized source code. and assist them when using and surfing the code, because it will be easier to use a code organized in folders and files than a very large code in a single file for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following GitHub conversation: [Allow directories in source generator outputs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/66438) , the solution to this problem is [not in VS 17.5.2, so you will have to use VS 17.6 Preview](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/66438#issuecomment-1477484123)